# What are the benefits of designing a KeyBinding relay?

Tags: architecture, input

The input system of Quake3 is handled using a Keybinding relay, whereby each keypress is matched against a 'binding' which is then passed to the [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_%28video_game_CLI%29) along with a time stamp of when the keypress (or release) occurred.

I just wanted to get an idea from developers what they considered to be the key benefits of designing your input system around this approach?
One thing i don't particularly like is the appending of the timestamp to the bound command. This seems like a bit of a hack to bend the CLI into handling the games input?
Also I feel that detecting the keypress only to add the command to a stream of text that gets parsed at a later date to be a slightly latent way of responding to input? (or is this unfounded?)

The only real benefit i can see is that it allows you to bind 'complex' commands to keypresses; like 'switch weapon;+fire;' for example. Or maybe for journaling purposes?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Maybe check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3076/keyboard-input-system-handling as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- It makes it very easy to implement customizable button assignment in your game.
- It makes programming very easy because you can think in abstract terms: You only have to decide what shall happen if the player input is "forward" for example, whether this "forward" comes from pressing the *up key*, *w*, an *analog stick* or even a *combination of keys*.
- A keybinding relay is an abstract concept and your implementation can differ from the one of Quake3. For example I wouldn't implement a timestamp if I didn't need a replay function. The overhead you're worried about is negligible if you query the whole controller state at once.